# Recursively check if all digits of a number are different

Tags: c++, recursion

How can I check recursively if all the digits of an integer are different numbers in C++

```
void Check(int n)  
{

    if (n < 10)  
        return;  
    else  
    {
        bool eq = !(n % 10 == ((n / 10) % 10));  
        if (eq == true)  
        {  
            Check(n / 10);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: why recursion - possible but not natural? Is this school homework?

Comment: show Your first attempt

Comment: my first attempt was to go through all digits but i can compare only two contiguous digits but i cannot compare one digit with every other and yes it is important homework

Comment: You can [edit] that in your question

Comment: You still need to store your previous digits.  `std::set` can be used for that.  Inserting will fail if the digit is already present

Comment: Also, a real check should at least return a boolean.

Comment: @stefaanv - a set is overkill when all you need is ten boolean values.

Comment: @PeteBecker: in what way? Will it take too long or too many memory, will you notice compilation time, will the executable double? It is a general tool and it is easily incorporated in this situation.  I like the other solutions too, but std::set is an easy solution too. `if (myset.insert(n%10).second)...`

Comment: @stefaanv - every entry in a `std::set` requires a memory allocation of a block that holds the data and, typically, three pointers. Adding an element requires walking the internal tree to find where that entry should go, and maybe shuffling tree entries around to maintain balance. Finding an entry requires walking the internal tree. That's an awful lot of overhead when all you need to do is hold ten bits, one for each of the digits 0 through 9.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I meant this from a conceivable and practical point of view as shown in my extra questions. Based on your profile and your comment, you really know the nitty gritty and I appreciate that, but my experience is that unless your project really needs all the resources, the standard library gives what you need, also thanks to the talented people who have worked on it.  I am aware of situation where other solutions are needed.

Comment: @stefaanv - `std::bitset` and `std::array` are also in the standard library, and support much simpler solutions that `std::set` for something as straightforward as this.

Answer (score 1):

You can remember, which digits you have already seen. For instance by using a bool-array of length 10. At the first call of your function all entries are `false`. In each recursive call you set `array[n%10]` to true. If it was already `true`, then you have found a duplicate digit, otherwise not.

If you want to only use recursion, you can define a second recursive function:

```
bool checkIfDigitApearsInNumber(int n, int digit) {
    if (n == 0) {
       return false;
    } else {
       if (n % 10 == digit) {
          return true;
       } else {
          return checkIfDigitApearsInNumber(n/10, digit);
       }
    }
}
```

In you function `Check`, you have to call this function in each step with `n/10, n%10`.